# Background Processes out-living gradle build

Tags: process, gradle

I am using [gradle-processes](https://github.com/johnrengelman/gradle-processes) to manage a set of long running services.

I am basing my tasks on JavaFork, and simply using the main class with classpath and arguments.

This is how it looks like:

```
    project.procs.javafork {
        main = "StartApp"
        environment += ["CLASSPATH": project.ext.localCP]
    }
```

On OSX, and Linux that works up the expectations, but on windows, the forked processes are dying on me after the gradle build is finished and gradle process is exited.

```
 :startMainApp
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL
 Total time: 1 mins 53.635 secs
 C:\projects\git\development\master>
```

Any idea ? or any settings I need to set to avoid my separate process to be terminated when gradle exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around I am using a different fork:

```
if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
    project.procs.fork {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c','java.exe com.me.StartApp"
        environment += ["CLASSPATH": project.ext.localCP]
    }
} else {
    project.procs.javafork {
        main = "com.me.StartApp"
        environment += ["CLASSPATH": project.ext.localCP]
    }
}
```